# What does the button labeled "intelligent Wi-Fi" do?

Tags: samsung, wi-fi, settings

My Android cellphone has a drop-down menu with four options:

- Wi-Fi Direct
- Intelligent Wi-Fi
- Advanced Settings
- Contact Us

[image: A screen capture of a drop down menu with four options]

It is Android 13 (Tiramisu). Additional information from the "about phone" menu:

> Software information
>
> One UI version
>
> Android version
>
> Google Play system update
> November 1, 2023
>
> Baseband version
> A546USQS5AWJ1
>
> Kernel version
> 5.15.78-android13-3-27100863
> #1 Tue Oct 3 10:39:23 KST 2023
>
> Build number
> TP1A.220624.014.A546USQS5AWJ1
>
> SE for Android status
> Enforcing
> SEPF_SM-A546U_13_0001
> Tue Oct 03 10:49:29 2023
>
> Knox version
> Knox 3.9
> Knox API level 36 HDM 2.0 - 7
>
> Service provider software version
> SAOMC_SM-A546U_OYN_CCT_13_0019
> CCT/CCT,CCT/CCT

Answer (score 3):

According to reporting from [SamMobile](https://www.sammobile.com/news/samsung-one-ui-5-0-intelligent-wi-fi-feature-dead-zone/), it allows for more detailed settings about Wi-Fi connectivity to help create a more seamless transition between various Wi-Fi networks and cellular data. Samsung's [feature announcement](https://www.samsung.com/ph/support/mobile-devices/enjoy-faster-connectivity-with-wi-fi-6e-and-intelligent-wi-fi/) from 2022 has some good details although a no-longer-working video, and their [Knox documentation page](https://docs.samsungknox.com/admin/knox-platform-for-enterprise/kbas/kba-360034073174/) has some more technical information. It implements features like:

- Grey area detection
- Preference tracking
- Suspicious hotspot detection
- Prioritizing preferential traffic (like video calls)
- Preemptive switching to cellular data if Wi-Fi is likely to be unstable

Here is an example of some of the settings that may be present (as Andrew T. mentioned, this is Samsung only and may vary among Samsung devices):

[image: Intelligent Wi-Fi settings]